# Add paragraph value to referenced node

Tags: nodes, 9, paragraphs

I have a paragraph with two field:

- `Paragraph title` [text field]
- `Node` [entity reference field]

The node is displaying its title and an image. By default the `Node title` is a H2 heading. But I want it to change based on the existence of the `Paragraph title`.

When the `Paragraph title` is set. The `Paragraph title` should be a H2 and the `Node title` should be a H3. But when the `Paragraph title` field is empty the `Node title` should be surrounded by a H2.

How can this be done?

Comment: There are **really many** questions and answers on this site about "get child paragraph from node" or "getting parent node of paragraph".

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use the hook `function template_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables)`.

In the hook function you can test if you are on a the proper paragraph and if you are on a Node object like this :

```
$paragraph_type = $variables['paragraph']->getType();
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

And then from here you can test if your Node has the value you want (the title) and if the paragraph_type is the correct type and return the good title in `$variables['my_new_title']`.

In twig template of the paragraph, you can then call `{{ my_new_title }}`.